# ¿Cómo abrir el code-snippet de una pregunta y ordenar el código fuente?

Tags: soporte, stack-snippets, ediciones

Esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53616/78) contiene un code-snippet donde veo que el código JavaScript no está ordenado/tabulado.

Me gustaría organizarlo, pero creo que el code-snippet cuenta con un botón para ordenar el código antes de publicarlo.

¿Hay alguna manera de abrir el code-snippet de una pregunta y presionar el botón "Ordenar", en lugar de organizar manualmente el código fuente después de haberlo publicado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Claro que se puede, simplemente tienes que realizar lo siguiente:

1. Click en editar pregunta, y te debería aparecer todo el código y el snippet a ejecutar. (Por lo que veo aún no cuentas con 1000 puntos de reputación los cuales son necesarios para editar preguntas sin la necesidad de aprobación de un usuario con mayor reputación a ti, sin embargo, puedes realizarlo de todas maneras y esperar por dicha aprobación).
2. Click en *edit the above snippet*

   [image: el enlace aparece debajo del Snippet]
3. Click en el botón de *ordenar*

   [image: el botón dentro del Stack Snippet, debajo de Guardar e insertar]

¡Listo! Código correctamente tabulado