# ¿Qué es Stack Snippet?

Tags: soporte, stack-snippets, propuesta-de-faq

Adaptación de [Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1595451)

## ¿Qué es lo que Stack Snippets hace?

**Stack Snippets hace ejecutables los bloques de código.** A continuación un ejemplo:

```js
alert("Pueden mostrar alertas");
```

```css
.hello {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">Stack Snippets permiten hacer ejecutable el código.</div>
```

## ¿Qué es lo que soportan?

Stack Snippets funcionan tanto en preguntas como en respuestas. Los lenguajes soportados son los siguientes:

- **HTML**
- **CSS**
- **JavaScript**

Puedes combinar estos tres lenguajes a tu gusto para crear código ejecutable para que otros lo prueben. El objetivo de esta característica es animar a los usuarios a crear código mínimamente viable y funcional cuando realicen preguntas centradas en el código. Las respuestas pueden ser en la forma de un stack snippet que ha resuelto la pregunta en cuestión. Esperamos que Stack Snippets permita a las personas no tener que ir a otros sitios web para producir código ejecutable.

Eventualmente, esperamos extender esto a otros lenguajes, pero empezamos con estos porque son fáciles de realizar en el navegador.

## ¿Cómo hago un stack snippet?

En la ventana del editor Markdown, verás un botón en el que puedes hacer clic para lanzar el editor Stack Snippets.

[image: Barra de herramientas del editor de Markdown]

El editor se mostrará en una vista de ventana-completa y permitirá la escritura de código HTML, CSS y JavaScript. Puedes usar cualquiera de ellos (debes usar al menos uno).

[image: Pantalla completa del editor de Stack Snippets]

Cuando termines, presiona **Guardar e Insertar** en la parte superior para insertar tu stack snippet en el texto Markdown. Será insertado como bloques de código Markdown regulares, más algunos comentarios que no se procesan, de tal forma que son compatibles con el historial de revisiones, Markdown paralelo, etc. Incluso puedes editar el código directo en el texto Markdown, en lugar de tener que hacerlo en el editor de pantalla-completa.

[image: Haz el Markdown por mí]

## ¿Por qué?

Todas las preguntas son mejores por tener *código mínimo, reproducible*. Anteriormente, la mejor forma de decirle a la gente que lo haga era dirigirlos a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), lo cual está fuera del sitio. Usando esta característica, alentamos a los nuevos autores para incrustar código ejecutable que reproduce su problema.

De igual forma, las respuestas que incluyan código ejecutable son más fáciles de usar y comprender, porque puedes probarlas. Obviamente JSFiddle es muy popular en las respuestas, por lo que solo queríamos que sea aún más fácil de usar.

Obviamente, se siguen aplicando las reglas: preguntas o respuestas de sólo código serán bloqueadas (y, de hecho, debido a cómo se implementa, todas las comprobaciones existentes *funcionarán de inmediato*).

## ¿Qué navegadores son soportados?

Actualmente, Stack Snippets estará activo para **cualquier navegador que soporte la característica iframe sandbox de  HTML5**. Esto casi se alínea con nuestra meta de soportar 2 liberaciones atrás de la versión actual de todos los navegadores modernos con excepción de IE9. [Ver este enlace para más información.](http://caniuse.com/#feat=iframe-sandbox)

Cuando esté inactivo, Stack Snippets se mostrará como bloques de código comunes, así que el código sigue siendo parte de una pregunta o respuesta.

## Pruébalo

[Aquí está un sandbox para probarlo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3293).

Los comentarios son bienvenidos y apreciados

NOTA: Si sabes inglés has directamente los comentarios en la publicación original.

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Comment: Por hacer: Incluir funciones relevantes anunciadas en [Feedback requested: Stack Snippets 2.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270944/1595451)

Comment: Posible fuente de ideas/mejoras [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1595451)

Comment: Otro más:  [How do I create a React Stack Snippet with JSX support?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/1595451)

Comment: Relacionado [¿Cómo abrir el code-snippet de una pregunta y ordenar el código fuente?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1545/65)

Answer (score 1):

Sin duda alguna una excelente herramienta que debería ser utilizada dentro de las preguntas cuyo contexto aplique.

Sin embargo (al menos yo no conocía la existencia de esta pregunta), es tremendamente útil pues en algunas publicaciones recientes veo que se aplica a tecnologías como:

- PHP
- SQL Language
- Java
- etc.

Entonces dentro del alcance de esta respuesta comento

¿Sería posible que el sistema impidiera usar un *stack snnipet* para tecnologías que están fuera del alcance del mismo?

Es decir no permitir el uso para tecnologías backend, ya que finalmente para el *AP* y/o para quien responde no ayudan por que no se podrá ejecutar el o los fragmentos de código que se están empleado en la publicación

Comment: La pregunta sobre "si sería posible que el sistema..." merece su propio hilo. Por cierto, en [meta.se] se han hablado de este tipo de cosas. En alguna publicación se menciona que existía (al menos al momento de la publicación) la intención de abarcar mas lenguajes.

Comment: gracias por el enlace @Rubén, cuando dices *su propio hilo* te refieres a una publicación propia?

Comment: Me refiero a la pregunta incluida en el cuerpo de esta respuesta publicarla como pregunta aquí en Meta, aunque por ser un tema que impactaría todos los sitios que usen Stack Snippet quizás sea más conveniente publicarla directamente en [meta.se].