# Prueba aquí Stack Snippets

Tags: discusión, stack-snippets

Esta pregunta está dedica a pruebas de Stack Snippets. Para mayor información véase [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292)

NOTA: Para publicar en meta se requiere el privilegio [Participar en Meta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) (5 puntos de reputación).

Para pruebas de formato, véase [Pruebas de formato (Sandbox)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1706/65)

Answer (score 1):

Modal en Stack Snippet. Adaptación de [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40071122/1595451) a [Open link in a popup window inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40063146/1595451)

```js
function doalert(obj) {
  var el = document.getElementById('here').src = (obj.getAttribute("value"));;
  return false;
}

var modal = document.getElementById('modinfo');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0]; 
function test() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<a onclick="doalert(this);test()" value="https://example.com">Link1</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modinfo" class="modal" style="display: none;">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 80%;background: white;border: none; border-radius: 0">
    <span class="close" style="cursor:pointer;color: #3D5872; font-size: 26px">x</span>
    <iframe id="here" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 310px;border: none;"></iframe>
  </div>
<!-- Modal content -->
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

> Nota: Esta respuesta se trata más de las ediciones y no tanto de la respuesta en sí misma.
>
> - https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4613/revisions
>
> Las ediciones importantes son desde la 2 hasta la 7 (aunque en la edición 2 erróneamente en la descripción puse que era la edición 1).
>
> En las ediciones, se puede ver cómo es que al fusionar los tres archivos, JavaScript, CSS y HTML, a veces el **markdown en paralelo** no hace cambios en el código.
>
> Lo importante es que al cambiar el orden de los lenguajes, en el markdown aparece todo en rojo a la izquierda y a la derecha aparece el mismo código pero en verde.
>
> A pesar de que cambia el orden de los lenguajes, al cambiar a **en paralelo**, el snippet se ve igual, en el mismo orden, JavaScript, CSS y HTML.
>
> Si el snippet no llega a aparecer al tocar **en paralelo**, aparecerá un enlace con el texto **completo**, que sirve para ver la respuesta completa. Este no es el caso ya que es una respuesta muy corta. Tal enlace aparece solo en respuestas largas.

Ejemplo de problema.

A continuación dejaré el código con snippet.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var elemento = document.querySelector("a")
  var texto = elemento.innerHTML
  var resultado = texto.slice(1) + texto.slice(0, 1)
  elemento.innerHTML = resultado
}, 500)
```

```css
center {
  color: #1020ff;
  background-color: #90e0a070;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<center><b><a> ¡Hola mundo! </a></b></center>
```