# Snippet, codigo oculto y resultado visible

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, respuesta, stack-snippets

### Edit:

He encontrado un post en el que ya se hacia está sugerencia como respuesta de [Feedback requested: Stack Snippets 2.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270959/11463270), bastante interesante donde en los comentarios argumentan por que no sería una buena idea.

---

Esto es una pregunta/sugerencia, ya que no tengo muy claro si se puede hacer.

Me preguntaba si es posible que el código del snippet no sea visible pero el resultado de este si.

**Imagen de ejemplo:**
[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Se que es posible hacer esto parcialmente, ocultando todo el snippet:

```js
document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML= "¡Hola mundo!";
```

```html
<div id="texto"></div>
```

Pero haciendo esto, me da la sensación de que el snippet puede pasar por alto.

La idea me surge, ya que contestando a preguntas me gusta poner un snippet enseñando la funcionalidad del código, pero muchas veces este snippet puede tener código que no sea necesario para responder a la pregunta, pero si ayuda a que se vea el resultado.
Al final acaba la respuesta con un muro de código...

Por lo que yo suelo hacer lo siguiente:

- Explicación
- `<pre>Ejemplo del código que responde a la pregunta</pre>`
- Snippet demostrativo, con código que no es necesario para la respuesta pero que ayuda a ver el resultado.

[Ejemplo de una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/266265/funci%C3%B3n-con-scroll/266456#266456)

1. ¿Se puede ocultar solo el código?
2. ¿Mi forma de responder es correcta?
3. ¿Deberia esconder todo el Snippet en caso de que contenga código irrelevante para la respuesta?

Comment: Lo que estas pidiendo seria una caracteristica nueva para toda la red. Suena interesante..

Comment: Creo que esto es posible pero en forma de bug, se puede ir probando diferentes combinaciones con Markdown, el snippet tiene que estar visible, pero combinando de alguna manera backticks (triple tilde invertida) o `<pre>`, quizás sea posible.

Comment: @ArtEze Interesante lo que comentas aunque no he podido simularlo. Pero he encontrado el siguiente post: como respuesta a [Feedback requested: Stack Snippets 2.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0/270959#270959) en el que en los comentarios se puede ver por que no sería muy recomendable que esto se pudiera hacer. Incluso si es posible hacer lo que comentas igual se debería de reportar :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Entiendo que una de tus preguntas es si al usar Stack Snippet se pueden ocultar las secciones de código HTML/CSS/JavaScript pero al mismo tiempo mostrar el botón ejecutar y el panel de resultado (y quizás la consola).

Según entiendo esto no es posible actualmente. Podrías hacer una solicitud de característica nueva y para ello, si te es posible, revisa primero si se ha propuesto anteriormente en Meta Stack Overflow y en Meta Stack Exchange, si no te es posible, publícala aquí y seguramente algún miembro de la comunidad / empleado de Stack Overflow Inc. que encuentre interesante tu solicitud lo haga por tí ( y por toda la comunidad).

En cuanto a si tu forma de responder es correcta, como aquí no es la escuela yo no la calificaría como correcta o incorrecta, pero si te digo que según lo describes me gusta y considero que otros usuarios hacen lo mismo ( por cierto yo he hecho algo similar en algunas preguntas, jeje).

Me parece que si tu código es extenso, indepedientemente de si incluye código "irrelevante" para responder la pregunta pero necesario para la demostración, si lo deberías esconder ya que sólo está a un clic de distancia ya que lo principal es la explicación.

Cabe mencionar que aunque algunos consideran a los sitios de Stack Overflow como fuente de snippets (entiéndase código listo para copiar y pegar) esto no es su propósito principal. En mi opinión lo principal son las explicaciones que responden las preguntas, el código es sólo un instrumento auxiliar para clarificar lo preguntado/respondido.

Relacionado

- [¿Qué es Stack Snippet?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/65)

Comment: Exacto, he editado mi pregunta añadiendo una imagen de ejemplo de lo que sugiero. Me imaginaba que no existía por que no lo había visto antes... Estoy de acuerdo en que lo importante es la explicación, si no mucha gente buscara el código y `ctrl + c` `ctrl +v`, pero también a mucha gente (me incluyo) le ayuda a entender la explicación. Gracias por tu respuesta!